# Error:org.opentest4j.AssertionFailed (Al comparar un string)

Tags: java, string, test, pruebas-unitarias

El codigo basicamente recibe un string y busca las coincidencias que hay en otro `Array` de `string` y crea un nuevo `Array` con lo filtrado.

El caso es que el código me da el resultado que espero pero luego en el Test me da error.

```
public static String[] foundValues(String foundValue, String ... value)  {
    int k=1;
    int h=0;
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<value.length;i++) {
        if(value[i]==foundValue) {
            h++;
        }
    }
    String[] s = new String[h];
    for(int i = 0;i<value.length;i++) {
        if(value[i]==foundValue) {
            s[j]=value[i]+" "+k;
            k++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    return s;
}


@Test
void test() {
    Library l=new Library();
    String[] s=new String[] {"Laura 1","Laura 2"};
    String[] f=new String[] {"Laura","Laura"};
    String[] j=l.foundValues("Laura", f);
    
    assertEquals(s,l.foundValues("Laura", f));
    /*Error:org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: [Ljava.lang.String;@27ff5d15<[Laura
    *1, Laura 2]> but was: [Ljava.lang.String;@4e096385<[Laura 1, Laura 2]>
    */
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vale lo he resuelto pero por si alguien llega aqui con mi misma duda me voy a responder.
Lo que hay que hacer es un metodo que recorra paso por paso los arrays y compruebe que son iguales en todo momento tal que asi:

```
public static boolean arraysStringIguales(String[] s2, String[] s1) {
        for(int i=0;i<s2.length;i++) {
            if(s2[i].equals(s1[i])) {
            }else return false;
        }return true;       
    }
```

Y luego el test seria de esta manera:

```
void test() {
        
        Library l=new Library();
        String[] s=new String[] {"Laura 1","Laura 2"};
        String[] f=new String[] {"Laura","Laura"};
        String[] j=l.foundValues("Laura", f);
        
        assertTrue(l.arraysStringIguales(s, j)); 
        
    }
```

Espero que haya ayudado a alguien con esto.